# How do I store rendered components and state when a user reloads the page?

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a dashboard app where the user can customize it to render their choice of components. Once they configure it, how can I save this state so that if the user revisits the app, it loads the same setup as when they left?

For example I have the following components available: `A, B, C, D, E`. The user configures their dashboard to render only `A, C, D`. I want to make it so when the user reloads or revisits the page, the same components (`A, C, D`) and their respective state are rendered. I don't want it so the user has to reconfigure the app each time.

I was thinking of storing the data in a text file but then I'm unsure how to convert that data back into a component. Any advice?

Comment: Have you tired storing their settings in a browser cookie? Otherwise you'd need someway to fingerprint the users session to serve them the correct data, or have them create an account so you can fetch from your api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about saving data in a browser, you have some options to pick from:

- Local storage
- Indexed DB
- Cookies

[Client-side storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Client-side_storage)

For react, you can also find stuff like `useLocalStorage` (like `useState`) for example that simplify usage of the above. Plain browser API may be already trivial enough, though.

But, actually, the solution may depend on how you define (identify) your "user". Is it a person who opened the browser? Or maybe a person who is logged in your application?